# How can I cover water stains on this wall

Tags: drywall, water, primer

During sandy storm I had some water leakage in my home. The damage isn't much in the sense that the drywall is still hard. It just has water stains that I'd like to get rid of.

Here is a pic of what the damage looks like. Yesterday night I applied a coat of water based primer on the drywall however, this morning the stain is still there.

Should I instead use an oil based primer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a good oil based primer like Kilz.

[image]

Put about 2 coats to cover the stains completely.  After this has dried completely you can touch up with latex based paint and this should prevent any further stains from seeping through.

Regular latex based primers are not going to do a good job of hiding previous water damage.  It may cover for a few weeks but eventually the stain will come back.

**NOTE:** Just make sure that you have addressed the source of the water first.  This shouldn't be used to sweep a problem under the carpet.  If the water damage continues then this will not help you.

Comment: There is a water based version of Kilz, but it doesn't work as sell, the label even says so.